# Bootstrap Order of Columns when collapsing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having difficulty with my first Bootstrap website, currently, my content under the main jumbotron is like this when the website is a full 1920x1080 page.

```
Statement   Image

Image   Statement

Statement   Image
```

But one unfortunate thing that is happening when my website collapses to the mobile sized version, the content displays like this

```
Statement

Image

Image

Statement

Image

Statement
```

This is obviously very off putting for the user, it leads the user into being confused as to which image goes with which statement and overall just messes with the currently flow of the web page. How do I change the bootstrap code to make the columns collapse differently so when I collapse to mobile the content displays such as

```
Statement

Image

Statement

Image

Statement

Image
```

I have had a hard time finding a solution for this problem and I am hoping someone else has dealt with this issue before, thanks in advance for anyone willing to help me out, means a lot.

The formatting is really weird, please just look at the jsfiddle

**HTML**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>ConjugateNow</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ConjugateNow.com</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Conjugator<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Games</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Premium</a>

      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Search">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Log In</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid fixMargin">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 lightgrey leftJumbo">
                 <div class="marginCenter">
                <h1 class="jumboHeader">Welcome to ConjugateNow.com</h1>
                <p>Conjugation technology fueling a generation of students, teachers, and learners</p>
                <iframe class="initialVideo "width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HHMxblMz3KI" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 darkgrey rightJumbo">
              <p class="formHeader">Make your free account now</p>
              <div class="formBox">
                <form>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="floatLeft">Email address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="floatLeft">Username</label>
                  <input type="user" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="floatLeft">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="floatLeft">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary signUpButton">Sign Up</button>
                </div>


              </form>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="container doubleColumnJumbotron">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6 darkgrey leftCol">
                    <h1>m Do Lore Lo m Do Lore Lo</h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore </p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6 darkgrey marginCenter">
                    <div id="leftColImg">
                    <img src="200x200.svg" >
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>   

          <div class="row paddingTopMain">
               <div class="col-md-6 darkgrey marginCenter">

                    <div id="leftColImg">
                    <img src="200x200.svg" >
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6 darkgrey leftCol">
                    <h1>m Do Lore Lo m Do Lore Lo</h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore </p>
               </div>
          </div>

           <div class="row paddingTopMain">
               <div class="col-md-6 darkgrey leftCol">
                    <h1>m Do Lore Lo m Do Lore Lo</h1>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore Lorem Ipsunm Do Lore </p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6 darkgrey marginCenter">
                    <div id="leftColImg">
                    <img src="200x200.svg" >
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>

          <div class="divider"></div>
          <div class="row callToAction paddingTopMain darkgrey">
               <div class="col-md-12 callToActionDiv">
               <h1>
                    What are you waiting for?     
               </h1>
               <h3>Start conjugating now for free</h3>
               <button>Go now</button>
               </div> 
          </div>
           <div class="divider"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4  bottomPageInfo ">
          <ul>
               <li class="initialListItem">ConjugateNow</li>    
               <li><a href="#">AAAAA</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">CCCC</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">EEEEE</a></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4  bottomPageInfo">
          <ul>
               <li class="initialListItem">Cooper Co.</li>    
               <li><a href="#">EEEEE</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">ZZZZZ</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">ZZZZZ</a></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4  bottomPageInfo">
          <ul>
               <li class="initialListItem">Our Team</li>    
               <li><a href="#">LLLLLLLL</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">EEEEEE</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">TTTTTTTT</a></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
     </div>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/mtpebs1x/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [column ordering classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes). For example, here **`order-md-2`** is put on the left `col-md-6` which makes the order of this column 2nd on `md` and up screen widths. On `sm` and `xs` screen widths the col will be ordered 1st.

https://www.codeply.com/go/H6IaMUGQyR

```
<div class="row paddingTopMain">
          <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2 darkgrey leftCol">
                  <h1>m Do Lore Lo m Do Lore Lo</h1>
                  <p>...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 darkgrey marginCenter">
                  <div id="leftColImg">
                  <img src="//placehold.it/200x200">
                  </div>
          </div>
</div>
```